# Data Science Experience responds with an empty Hive table

Tags: hive, pyspark, ibm-cloud, biginsights, data-science-experience

From my Data Science Experience, I am able to make a connection to the Hive database in BigInsights and read the table schema. But Data Science Experience does not seem to be able to read the table contents as I get a count of zero! Here are some of my settings:

```
conf = (SparkConf().set("com.ibm.analytics.metadata.enabled","false"))      

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()    

dash = {
'jdbcurl': 'jdbc:hive2://nnnnnnnnnnn:10000/;ssl=true;',
'user': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
'password': 'xxxxxxxxx',
}    

spark.conf     

offers = spark.read.jdbc(dash['jdbcurl'],
                     table='offers', 
                     properties={"user" : dash["user"], 
                                 "password" : dash["password"]})    

offers.count()       returns:  0

offers.show()       
  returns:

+-----------+----------+    
|offers.name|offers.age|    
+-----------+----------+    
+-----------+----------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i was able to see same behaviour with hive jdbc connector.
I tried this python connector and it returned correct count.

https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/python_load.html

`from ingest.Connectors import Connectors`

```
`HiveloadOptions = { Connectors.Hive.HOST                        : 'bi-hadoop-prod-4222.bi.services.us-south.bluemix.net',
                  Connectors.Hive.PORT                      : '10000',
                  Connectors.Hive.SSL                       : True,
                  Connectors.Hive.DATABASE                  : 'default',
                  Connectors.Hive.USERNAME                  : 'charles',
                  Connectors.Hive.PASSWORD                  : 'march14march',
                  Connectors.Hive.SOURCE_TABLE_NAME         : 'student'}
```

`

```
`HiveDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.ibm.spark.discover").options(**HiveloadOptions).load()`
```

`HiveDF.printSchema()`

`HiveDF.show()`

`HiveDF.count()`

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: What package I should install to resolve 'from ingest.Connectors import Connectors' ?